# Set decimal places for pyplot axis tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I want to use `np.arange()` to define axis tick labels. But several labels go out to crazy decimal places (e.g., 0.850000000000000001 instead of 0.85). Using `np.around()` to 2 decimals does not help either because then the numbers have alternating decimal places (0.45, 0.5, 0.55...). How can I just have it write each tick label to 2 decimals? Also, I'll want to change `fontsize` for these labels so I need to call `ax.set_yticklabels()`

```
x,y = np.arange(0,1,.05), np.arange(0,1,.05)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,1,.05))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(0,1,.05))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just eliminate the ax.set_yticklabels().  You get the desired result without it.

```
x,y = np.arange(0,1,.05), np.arange(0,1,.05)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,1,.05))
```

[image]

You can change the fontsize for your yticklabels as shown here:

```
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=8)
x,y = np.arange(0,1,.05), np.arange(0,1,.05)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,1,.05))
```

[image]

Comment: @jklaus - See my amended answer in response to your second question about font size.